# Decomposition of simplicial G-sets as a colimits of its simplicial G-subsets 

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Every simplicial set is the colimit of its finite simplicial subsets. Suppose $G$ be a finite discrete set.

Is every simplicial $G$-set a colimit of its finite simplicial $G$-subsets? I'm particularly interested in the case where $G={\mathbb{Z}}/2$.

Comment: "Every simplicial set is the colimit of its finite simplicial subsets. " Really? I doubt that this is true. Or what notion of "finite" are you working with here?

Comment: The obvious way of making the statement true is to replace "finite" by "finitely presented" (in the sense of Gabriel and Ulmer). But I think this turns out to be the same thing as a simplicial set with finitely many non-degenerate simplices.

Comment: So does this mean that the Ind-completion of finitely-presented simplicial sets is the category of all simplicial sets?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant $G$ should be a finite discrete *group*?  Also, I think the answer is yes.  Every simplex of a $G$-sset is contained in a finite sub-*sset*, and then you you can take the closure under the $G$-action (which will still be finite, since $G$ is).  This closure will be a sub-sset because the face and degeneracy maps are $G$-equivariant.